# Pulling changes from original to fork - bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have fork from original repository. How I could pull updates from original repository to my fork when new branches were created in original repo ? I use git and bitbucket.

Comment: Here's a [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944898/bitbucket-update-a-fork-to-merge-changes-of-master-repo) SO question that can help you.

Comment: Yes, It's ok when we want to update existing in our fork branch, but when this is a new branch I receive `fatal: remotes/origin/release1 - not something we can merge
`

Answer (score 3):

Github has a great page describing how to do it: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

1. git remote add upstream [your-original-repo-git-url]
2. git fetch upstream
3. git merge upstream/master

yay!

If you want alternative branches, after step 2, you'll be able to see them. So if upstream has creating 1-3-stable:

```
git checkout -b 1-3-stable  
git merge upstream/master
```