# How to sync with the original repository in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Although I have already checked the similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944898/bitbucket-update-a-fork-to-merge-changes-of-master-repo) about syncing my local files with the original repo I have this strange problem.

So, this is what I did:-

- I forked a repo from one of the existing repo in bitbucket.org, let's call it *master
  repo* which is (private repo) to my repo.
- I cloned my repo to my computer using:-

  ```
  git clone https://myself@bitbucket.org/myself/myrepo.git
  ```
- Now I want to see what changes has been made in the *master repo* so I did:-

  ```
  git remote add upstream https://masterrepo@bitbucket.org/masterrepo/master.git
  git pull upstream
  ```

But the problem is that git is asking for the password of masterrepo@bitbucket.org which I do not have.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I thought it was supposed to fetch and merge it into my current branch but it keeps asking the password for masterrepo@bitbucket.org.

I even tried entering my own password which clearly failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git` is asking for the password because the URL you used for the `upstream`:

```
https://masterrepo@bitbucket.org/masterrepo/master.git
```

is a HTTPS URL which requires authentication.

It is not quite clear from your question, but I'm guessing that `masterrepo` is a public repository (if not you could not have cloned it in the first place I assume). So try using a public URL which does not require authentication, while adding the `upstream` remote, one of these should work:

```
https://bitbucket.org/masterrepo/master.git
git@bitbucket.org:masterrepo/master.git
```

Comment: I am indeed using a private repo. I have access to this repo cause the owner of this repo sent me an invite. That's how I was able to fork and clone the repo.

However, your url did work. It now asks me for **my** username and password which it was previously just asking for the password of *master repo*. Thanks!